# OneToMany Relation using EmbeddedId and Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create two tables State and Districts each are related to **OnetoMany** (State has multiple Districts) and I am using following properties to let Spring auto create tables from the defined java entities

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Here is the **StateEntity** class

```
@Table(name="STATE")
@Entity
public class StateEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StateIdentity stateIdentity;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "state" )
    private Set<DistrictEntity> districtSet;
    ....FOLLOWED BY GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

Here is the **StateIdentity** class;

```
@Embeddable
public class StateIdentity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3209414245070180550L;
    private int stateId;
    ....FOLLOWED BY GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

Here is the **DistrictEntity** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISTRICT")
public class DistrictEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DistrictIdentity districtIdentity;
    private StateEntity state;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STATE_ID", nullable=false)
    public StateEntity getState() {
        return state;
    }
    ....FOLLOWED BY GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

Here is the **DistrictIdentity** class;

```
@Embeddable
public class DistrictIdentity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7120909854467388901L;
    private int districtId;
    ....FOLLOWED BY GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

The application is running fine and creating tables but the one to many relation ship is missing. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `one to many relation ship is missing` ? Are you getting any error  ?

Comment: Maybe it's a one to many relation boat?  ..... sorry :-D